sed + match word in lines and replaced value with some conditions
we want to prepare sed approach in order to change the value of the key - ParallelGCThreads , and this will happened only on matched word in the line as HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS
more Hadoop-specific-environment.txt
.
.

export HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS="-server -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/$USER/hs_err_pid%p.log 
.
.

so we prepared the following sed syntax
val-32
HADOOP_OPTS=HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS

sed -i "/$HADOOP_OPTS/s/-XX:ParallelGCThreads=[0-9]*/-XX:ParallelGCThreads=$val/"  Hadoop-specific-environment.txt

above sed works fine but we have some problems

in case key - ParallelGCThreads is null ( without value ) then replaced will failed
ParallelGCThreads=

value will replaced even line is in comment
#export HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS=


what are the right corrections in order to solved above issues
any other suggestion will welcome include with perl one liner

this seems like a very fragile way of updating. why not refactor Hadoop-specific-environment.txt to make your changes easy? If it is a shell script anyway, just prepend a line myvar=value and use $myvar in the export line. now finding the line to change is trivial. or it could source an override file

=[0-9]* should be replaced with (=[0-9]*)?.
^[^#]* should be added at the beginning of first regex.
sed -i -E "/^[^#]*$HADOOP_OPTS/s/-XX:ParallelGCThreads(=[0-9]*)?/-XX:ParallelGCThreads=$val/" Hadoop-specific-environment.txt


Does not work if ParallelGCThreads doesn't have a number

@Bayou In my case it works with -E ,-r or --regexp-extended option

Wasn't arguing about -E or -r, but about this sentence in the post: in case key - ParallelGCThreads is null ( without value ) then replaced will failed

this could change comment instead of value in lines like export var=value # comment; also consider (=[0-9]*)? instead of =[0-9]+ to catch all of a=n / a= and a

technically, should probably also require leading whitespace before -XX:  and trailing whitespace or double-quote. but that might be overkill

also, like @bayou's current answer, this will change a line like NOT_HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS= if it contains the parameter, again an edge case but ...

I test your sed but in case -XX:ParallelGCThreads=   is without value , then sed not add the value as -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16

@Judy I thought that it should not be added in this case. Then use (=[0-9]*)? instead of =[0-9]*.

You need to create groups so you can directly jump to the part you want to change. Don't forget to add the -i option yourself after checking the output.
$ cat Hadoop-specific-environment.txt 
export HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS="-server -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/$USER/hs_err_pid%p.log"
export HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS="-server -XX:ParallelGCThreads= -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/$USER/hs_err_pid%p.log"
** test test test **
export HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS="-server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/$USER/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:ParallelGCThreads="
#export HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS="-server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/$USER/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:ParallelGCThreads="
** some other exports **

$ sed -r '/^[^#].*HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS=/ s/^(.*ParallelGCThreads)=[0-9]*(.+)$/\1=42\2/' Hadoop-specific-environment.txt
export HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS="-server -XX:ParallelGCThreads=42 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/$USER/hs_err_pid%p.log"
export HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS="-server -XX:ParallelGCThreads=42 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/$USER/hs_err_pid%p.log"
** test test test **
export HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS="-server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/$USER/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:ParallelGCThreads=42"
#export HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS="-server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/$USER/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:ParallelGCThreads="
** some other exports **

Regex explanation:
/^[^#].*HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS=/ -> must be an uncommented HADOOP_DATA_NODE_OPTS variable.

s/^(.*ParallelGCThreads)=[0-9]*(.+)$/
^(.*ParallelGCThreads)   -> Group \1: Everything until variable
=[0-9]*                  -> skipped, overwritten later
(.+)$                    -> Group \2: The rest you want

/\1=42\2/
\1                       -> Show first group
=42                      -> Use 42 ParallelGCThreads
\2                       -> Show second group


@jhnc. See problem 1 in the original post. Comments is valid tho. Fixing that.

wouldn't (=[0-9]*)? be cleaner? also, not clear from question but doesn't handle complete non-existence of ParallelGCThreads (a different interpretation of is null (without value)

might also want to use [^#]* instead of .* to handle case of lines like export var=value # comment

If the variable does not exist it doesn't do anything because the regex fails to match. Making a group in between gets confusing when you're dealing with a lot of groups, so I tend not to make too much of them.

yes, but if the idea is to set the parameter to 32, I'd expect the export line to need changing anyway

(my point with (=[0-9]*)? was to catch all of a=b / a= and a )

Would be [=0-9]* an okay middle ground?

only OP can say. it catches malformed cases, =1=2=3=4=5 but that may not be a problem
